# Where to find the possible commands for custom shortcuts in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

So I would like to modfiy a Jupyter notebook, so instead of having S for Save AND checkpoint, then there would be a button that just saves it without making a checkpoint.
I have found this [here](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Custom%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.html) that describes how to add shortcuts using the custom.js, and that example works fine. My question is then, where do I find the information that the function for executing is called `IPython.notebook.execute_cell();` or if I want to do something else, what is it called then? 
is there a list somewhere that I have missed, or do I just have to dig through the source until I find what I need?

Comment: You may want to try the [Keyboard shortcut editor](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/keyboard_shortcut_editor/README.html) which is one the extensions provided by `jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

Comment: thanks, that at least gives me the possible commands. However I see two S and Ctrl + S that both does checkpoint + save, but none with the possibility of just save.

Comment: Stelios could you add an answer, then I will close the question

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Well I solved the part you helped me with, I never found a solution for saving without making checkpoints. But it seem nobody else wants to do that, so I thought it was better to close it